# Create a Virtual Directory under a Web Application using WIX

Tags: iis, wix, wix3.5

I would like to add a Virtual directory to my Web Application that points to a certain folder outside the TARGETDIR,

any idea or example of how could I achieve this with WIX?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebVirtualDir` element must point to a `Directory` element. Fortunately, you can easily retarget a `Directory` in many different ways. Assuming a directory tree like this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="Source">
  <Directory Id="VIRTUALDIR" Name="retargeted">
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

And Component like:

```
<Component Id="Vdir" Directory="VIRTUALDIR">
   <File Source="myweb.dll" />
   <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="Myvdir" Directory="VIRTUALDIR" Alias="my/app/here" />
</Component>
```

Now you can treat the `VIRTUALDIR` like a `Property`. Because it is all caps you can set it on the command-line:

```
msiexec /i foo.msi /l*v log.txt VIRTUALDIR=C:\root\web\vdirhere
```

Or set it via a UI element in an MSI dialog (too much code to show example) or even use a search to set it:

```
<Property Id="VIRTUALDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="FindPlaceToPutVdir" ... />
</Property>
```

Lots of options.